# Laravel @can blade policy check up

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm writing blade policy for a drop down menu in laravel using @can.

```
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle"><i class="zmdi zmdi-assignment-o"></i><span>Models</span></a>
  <ul class="ml-menu">
    @can('index',App\Model1::class)
   <li>
      <a href="#">{{__('Model1 Manger')}}</a>
    </li>
    @endcan
    @can('index',App\Model2::class)
    <li>
       <a href="#">{{__('Model2 Manager')}}</a>
    </li>
    @endcan
   </ul>
  </li>
```

My question is how to hide the 'Model' option from the menu If user don't have permisssion to access model1 and model2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `can` within an if statement similar to below:

```
@if (Auth::user()->can('index',App\Model1::class) && Auth::user()->can('index',App\Model2::class))

@endif
```

You can find further information on Laravel's website at the link below:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-blade-templates

---

To take my answer further, it might be worth creating a separate class to handle authorization and then call it in the blade:

```
@if(BlogPermissions('showModal'))

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create policy for that. check the below code and for more reference check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#generating-policies

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Post;

class PostPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given post can be updated by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
}
```